# How do I disable incremental repair?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1, datastax-startup

I have a cluster which I am considering enabling incremental repair on. If anything goes wrong I'd like to disable incremental repair on every node. How do I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn node off and use `sstablerepairedset` to remove the repair time for each sstable so that they will all be candidates for future compactions.

```
find '/path/cassandra/data/keyspace/table/' -iname "*Data.db*" > sstables.txt

sudo -u cassandra sstablerepairedset --is-unrepaired -f sstables.txt
```

Then just go back to using `repair` with no `-inc` or in later versions use the `-full` flag